# Use the value of a DIV in a Javascript method to perform a calculation

Tags: javascript, html

The following `<div>` returns an integer between `0-1`.

```
<div id=value></div>
```

The above DIV returns a number for example : 0.75.

I want to use this value returned in a javascript method. How can i do it?

```
 function getRandomArbitrary() {
    def number =Math.random() * <<THE VALUE THAT I OBTAINED FROM THE ABOVE DIV TAG>>;

     return number;
}
```

Comment: id's have to start with a letter. Pure number is invalid.

Comment: It's displayed as a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "[the] div returns a number"? Do you mean that hte div contains a number? Or does it have a `data-` attribute with a number? Is the `id` the number? or...?

Comment: I just replaced `number` with `value`. It's just a string.

Comment: For what you are doing I would recommend using a `data-` attribute. Like `<div data-number="0.75"></div>`

Comment: @MartinErnst: No, HTML doesn't care about the content of IDs other than that they can't have spaces: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute And browsers never have. The only issue with IDs starting with digits is around CSS, not HTML.

Comment: @moss Please look at the post. I updated it. I know that an ID has to start with a letter. `number` is not a digit. It's just a value. A string.

Comment: @moss: No, MartinErnst is not correct (see above). But I'm with you on the `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Actually, just noticed, in HTML5 an ID can be a number, HTML4 it was not allowed. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Illep Perhaps you could add an example with an actual id you would be using and an actual number to retrieve rather than pseudo-syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the value that is inside the tag, for example `<div id=value>1</div>`, you can use `.innerHTML`. To be sure that the inside of a div is, in fact, a floating point number, wrap it in `parseFloat` (for example, if the div contains "abc", parseFloat will return 0).

In your case:

```
function getRandomArbitrary() {
    var number =Math.random() * parseFloat(document.getElementById('value').innerHTML);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what i am looking for. Anyway, i'll update you after trying it out.

Comment: I changed parseInt to parseFloat in the code because I noticed your original post said that 0.75 is a possibility for the value, which is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomArbitrary(elID) {
   return Math.random() * parseFloat(document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML);
}


getRandomArbitrary("number");
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/xeqoqi/1/edit?js,console,output)

The above is in the case you have something like:

```
<div id=number>0.75</div>
```

---

If you really want to store a **value inside a DIV** the good way to do it is to use the
`data-*` attribute like:

```
<div id=number data-value="0.75"></div>
```

would lead to this change in code:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById(elID).dataset.value);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/xeqoqi/3/edit)